cannot get a tag value under a multiple class from an HTML page with selenium pthon
I want to extract  'xms'  from the following HTML
    <div class="ki-kullaniciadi member-info" member-info-memberid="12789" member-info-forumid="2613">

            <a href="/profil/12789">
            
                <b>xms</b>
            </a>
        </div>

I have tried
def scrapecomments2(url):
  tic = time.perf_counter()
  wait = WebDriverWait(wd,20)
  wd.get(url)

  data2=[]


  for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ki-kullaniciadi.member-info b"))):
          data2.append(comment.text)


  toc = time.perf_counter()
  print(data2)
  return data2

including many combinations like
for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ki-kullaniciadi     b"))):
          data2.append(comment.text)

for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ki-kullaniciadi']/a/b"))):
      data2.append(comment.text)

It returned always
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e105fdffd5ff> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 scrapev2=scrapecomments2('https://forum.donanimhaber.com/tesla-model-y-kullananlar-kulubu-2023--155488676-1151')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
    103             if time.monotonic() > end_time:
    104                 break
--> 105         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    106 
    107     def until_not(self, method: Callable[[D], T], message: str = "") -> Union[T, Literal[True]]:

TimeoutException: Message: 

But
for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,"b"))):
          data2.append(comment.text)

worked, so it does not look like a problem with loading of the page. It returns every value with tag b in the page but I want only the ones onder class "ki-kullaniciadi member-info".
Thank you for the comment. I tried
for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'ki-kullaniciadi')]/a/b"))):
it returned the same error. But by chance I noticed that the following code worked and returned 'xms'.
for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "icerik b"))):
data2.append(comment.text)
I did not understand why it worked that way. Any comments. I attached the html;


I see TimeoutException in your error logs. TimeoutException comes when the expected elements are not found even after waiting for a certain limit. just check it once.

also try this as well for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'ki-kullaniciadi')]/a/b"))):
